# Why is it necessary to solve for x using both 1 and 2 why not just just any one of them?

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose one wants to find the complex number which is mirror image of a complex number $z_°$ about the line joining $z_1$ and $z_2$ . Here i have showed the process which i would have progressed with , my one query is that as x(complex number we wanted) is a single variable and we have two equations 1 and 2 ,why is that we need to utilize both equations to solve for x , why not from any one of the equation we will be able to get the result required ? [image]

Comment: If you specify only $z_1$ you cannot define $x$ in unique way, so you need both $z_1$ and $z_2$, then you need both equations. Or you can write equation in some other form, like $x-z_1=\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z_2-z_1}+\bar{\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z_2-z_1}\right)}\right)(z_2-z_1)-(z-z_1)$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu yeah i understood but whats wrong with this reason : as x is only a single variable so we need just one equation involving x to solve for it isnt ?

Comment: You always can write one equation from the system: $a(x)=0 \land b(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow |a(x)|^2+|b(x)|^2=0$.

Comment: You always can write equation for single variable that does not determine it in unique way, so you'll need additional equation. For example, for real variable $x$ equation $|x+a|-|x-a|=2a$ does not define $x$ as unique value. So you need to write right equation. You final result is also single equation for determination of single variable $x$ but it determines it in unique way.

Comment: Hmm this makes it all clear , thanks a lot @IvanKaznacheyeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you two reasons why you need both equations: an algebraic reason; and a geometric reason.

**Algebraic Reason:** Equation (1) does not involve the point $z_2$. Why would one expect equation (1) to give you any information whatsoever about $z_2$? Furthermore, your final solution does involve the quantity $z_2$. How could you derive a solution like that starting only from an equation, such as Equation (1), which does not involve the quantity $z_2$?

**Geometric Reason:** Equation (1) is *equivalent* to the initial equation $|x-z_1|=|z_0-z_1|$ which says:

> *Equation (1) in words:* $x$ lies on the circle $C_1$ with center $z_1$ of radius equal to $|z_0-z_1|$.

whereas equation (2) is equivalent to the equation $|x-z_2|=|z_0-z_2|$ which says

> *Equation (2) in words:* $x$ lies on the circle $C_2$ with center $z_2$ of radius equal to $|z_0-z_2|.

Why would one expect that *Equation (1) in words* would imply *Equation (2) in words*? As $x$ spins around the circle $C_1$, the distance from $x$ to $z_2$ rises and falls, and so $x$ certainly does not stay on any one single circle centered on $z_2$ such as $C_2$.